# Add a row to an empty recyclerview on execution time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with an `AutoCompleteTextView` and a button, and below it, a hidden `RecyclerView`, that starts empty (with no rows).

With the `AutoCompleteTextView`, I select an object and what I want is, when I click the button, to add that object to the `RecyclerView`(and turn the visibility on for the recycler).

So far, I've managed to add the object to the recycler's DataSet, but it won't show any row on `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/ib_add"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
        android:onClick="onAddClick"/>

<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/actv_input"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ib_add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ib_add"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The Activity (just the relevant functions):

```
@Bind(R.id.rv) RecyclerView rv;

ArrayList<Ing> ings = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Ing> selectedIngs = new ArrayList<>();

private void setupRecyclers() {
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(selectedIngs));
}

public void onAddClick(View view) {
    Ing ing = ings.get(selectedPosition);
    rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    selectedIngs.add(ing);
    ((RecyclerViewAdapter)rv.getAdapter()).addIng(ing);
}
```

The RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Ing> ings;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Ing> ings) {
    this.ings = ings;
}

@Override
public RViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_ing, parent, false);
    return new RViewHolder(row);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Ing ing = ings.get(position);
    holder.bindToView(ing);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ings.size();
}

public void addIng(Ing ing) {
    ings.add(ing);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setDataSet(ArrayList<Ing> ings) {
    this.ings = ings;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

The RecyclerViewHolder:

```
public class RViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

Ing ing;
ImageView ivIcon;
TextView tvName;
ImageButton ibRemove;
TextView tvPercentage;
EditText etPercentage;

public RViewHolder(View row) {
    super(row);

    bindFields(row);
}

private void bindFields(View view) {

    ivIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon_type);
    tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ing);
    ibRemove = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
    tvPercentage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_percentage);
    etPercentage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_percentage);

}

public void bindToView(Ing ing){
    this.ing = ing;

    tvName.setText(ing.getName());
    ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    tvName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ibRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvPercentage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    etPercentage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show the root element in your xml..? you don't need to set visibility off and on because when the list is empty you cannot see the recyclerview anyway.

Comment: also you are adding an item two times to the list

Comment: Hi @RaviTeja, I've done some testing on my project, and what I've gathered from them is that, no matter what, the onBindViewHolder method is never called. Even if I hardcode an element into the Array before the first call. I've also tried with and without visibility settings but it keeps working the same way (not working) :P

Comment: I've also checked what you said about adding the item two times, but in my tests, that's not happening, I'm adding it just once.

Comment: I've managed to show a hardcoded object into the recyclerView. The problem was that the Recycler, inside the Layout and the NestedScroll had some problems with the height. The support library's 23.2.0 update fixed this and allowed auto measure for the recycler, so it fixed this. However, the button won't add a new row anyway, so I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The first part, the recycler not showing even with an element inside, was fixed by the 23.2.0 support library's update, that introduced auto measurement for recyclerviews. Before that, if you had a recycler within a relative within a nested, it did some funny business and never initialized the rows inside the recycler.

The second part, the button not adding the row, was because even if you have some onclick event set in your image button, it looks that you have to put android:clickable = true or else it won't work.